# How would I use a custom Type Enum in a PostgreSQL SELECT statement?

Tags: postgresql

I have a custom enumeration type in PostgreSQL 13 defined as:

```
CREATE TYPE public.dbscale AS ENUM
    ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'Z');
```

When I try to make use of the `dbscale` ENUM in the sub-select below, I get an

`error: 42703 column \"dbscale"\ does not exist`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.xfertodecibellog(
    jobid integer,
    instid integer)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO decibellog(jobid, 
                           instrumentid,
                           readingdate,
                           readingtime,
                           decibelreading,
                           dbweighting)
    SELECT @jobid,
           @instid,
           CAST(dbdate AS date),
           CAST(dbtime AS time),
           CAST(dbvalue AS double precision),
           CASE dbunit 
                WHEN 'dB(B)' THEN (dbscale).B
                WHEN 'dB(C)' THEN (dbscale).C
                WHEN 'dB(D)' THEN (dbscale).D
                WHEN 'dB(Z)' THEN (dbscale).Z
                ELSE (dbscale).A
           END
    FROM stagingdecibellog;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like in the example in the section [Declaration of Enumerated Types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html#id-1.5.7.15.5) you can use ENUM values like text values ('A'), or (public.dbscale 'B') if you want to explicitly provide the type of the value.
The query would look like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.xfertodecibellog(
    jobid integer,
    instid integer)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO decibellog(jobid, 
                           instrumentid,
                           readingdate,
                           readingtime,
                           decibelreading,
                           dbweighting)
    SELECT @jobid,
           @instid,
           CAST(dbdate AS date),
           CAST(dbtime AS time),
           CAST(dbvalue AS double precision),
           CASE dbunit 
                WHEN 'dB(B)' THEN (public.dbscale 'B')
                WHEN 'dB(C)' THEN (public.dbscale 'C')
                WHEN 'dB(D)' THEN (public.dbscale 'D')
                WHEN 'dB(Z)' THEN (public.dbscale 'Z')
                ELSE (public.dbscale 'A')
           END
    FROM stagingdecibellog;
END;
$BODY$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a version of the SQL that solved the issue.

The example from Julius is also a solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.xfertodecibellog(
    jobid integer,
    instid integer)
    RETURNS void
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO decibellog(jobid, 
                           instrumentid,
                           readingdate,
                           readingtime,
                           decibelreading,
                           dbweighting)
    SELECT @jobid,
           @instid,
           CAST(dbdate AS date),
           CAST(dbtime AS time),
           CAST(dbvalue AS double precision),
           CASE dbunit 
                WHEN 'dB(B)' THEN 'B'::dbscale
                WHEN 'dB(C)' THEN 'C'::dbscale
                WHEN 'dB(D)' THEN 'D'::dbscale
                WHEN 'dB(Z)' THEN 'Z'::dbscale
                ELSE 'A'::dbscale
           END
    FROM stagingdecibellog;
END;
$BODY$;
```